# Why is my MEVN app only showing the backend when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, heroku, vuejs2

My app is currently deployed online through Heroku but it is displaying the backend server rather than my Vue app.

Note: I have an if statement in app.js that serves the files only in production.  I removed the if statement to see if the app would appear *without* environmental conditions. It did not work.

Also I have a minified Vue js folder called dist in my express directory.

**Updated**

The heroku method I am using is the Heroku Git Cli

```
$ cd my-project/
$ git init
$ heroku git:remote -a testingew
```

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

This is what I see, which is the backend response to the "/" route. The code is in app.js

[image]

**app.js**
The full code

```
const serveStatic = require("serve-static");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const budgetRoutes = require("./routes/budget");
const profileRoutes = require("./routes/profile");
require("dotenv/config");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const cors = require("cors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const sessions = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(sessions);
const passport = require("passport");
const passportSetup = require("./config/passport.js");

//Log when making request
app.use(morgan("combined"));

//Parse body for post request
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var corsOption = {
  origin: true,
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true
};

app.use(cors(corsOption));

app.use(
  sessions({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_COOKIEKEY,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: new MongoStore({
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
    }),
    cookie: {
      // secure: true,
      maxAge: 86400000
    }
  })
);

//Initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Automatic route placer
app.use("/auth", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/budget", budgetRoutes);
app.use("/api/profile", profileRoutes);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("App is on");
});

//404 error and pas to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("An error has occured");
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});

//Error handler
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  //Respond Client
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message
    }
  });
  console.log(error.message);
});

//Mongo connection
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECTION,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  },
  () => console.log("connected to mongo atlas")
);

//Handle production
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));

// Redirect all requests to `index.html`
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"));
});
//Start app
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Vue Router**

Note: I am also using route navigation guards within components if that means anything

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

//import axios from "axios";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "login",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/Login.vue")
  },
  {
    path: "/userprofile",
    name: "userProfile",
    component: () => import("../views/userProfile.vue"),
    meta: {
      requireAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/budgetform",
    name: "form",
    component: () => import("../views/budgetForm.vue"),
    meta: {
      requireAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/mybudget",
    name: "myBudget",
    component: () => import("../views/myBudget.vue"),
    meta: {
      requireAuth: true
    }
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

export default router;
```

File directory of Express

[image: Screenshot of file directory]

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

Based on your edit showing your Express app, you need to remove everything between

```
app.use("/api/profile", profileRoutes);
```

and `Mongo`.  The app can't run if you do other things on the route instead.  The "App is on" and error checking stuff is blocking your app.  I don't think you mean to run the error on every route, but that's what's happening.  I would suggest browsing some Express tutorials and starting from scratch to try to understand why that can't work.

## ORIGINAL

Try to replace everything above `app.listen` with:

```
// Serve static assets
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Redirect all requests to `index.html`
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
})
```

Your wildcard match was wrong, and would only match file paths that begin with a dot,  `path.join` wasn't used correctly, there should be no slash literals.  I changed some other syntax too.  If this doesn't completely fix the issue, there are many possibilities for error that are beyond the scope of this question:

1) directory structure
2) .gitignore
3) vue-router
4) package.json `start` script

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I tried replacing the above to the above code and nothing changed.  I can edit my question with some more info

Comment: if nothing else, 404 errors should now redirect to `index.html` and not so before. 
 Questions:  1) What do you see when you view the app?  2) Can you show your vue-router?  3) Which Heroku deploy method are you using?

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I will do more research as I thought error handling was a vital part of an Express app

Comment: Sure.  You can only send one response per request.  You are sending "app is on" for the root request, so nothing else happens.  If you removed that, you'd have the same problem with the error checking, which is sending back an error message on every single route instead of delivering your actual files or app.  Your code needs to make sure there is an actual error before sending an error instead of doing it every time.  All of this stuff is getting in the way of serving up your app.  Try to get it working locally first before trying it on Heroku.

Comment: Ahhh I see, so the app is defaulting to "app is on" over any other request. Sending "app is on" was ok in development because I was not redirecting all request to dist/index.html yet.

Comment: It wasn't ok in development either because it prevents serving index.html at the root. Once that response is sent, the server can't send anything else, i.e. index.html because: one response only.

Now that's just on the root.  All other requests get snagged by the error checking, which is acting like a 404.  Reason is `app.use` with no path arg runs on every route and since you send a response there, same problem, now the server can't send index.html later.

The stuff underneath (static files, wildcard redirect) never send any response since one has already been sent.